# soap listener for docusign in .net

Tags: soap, listener, docusignapi

I have configured a web service below to be called by Docusign on sent event. Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using DocusignApi;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using MCFTech.Vology.QbWrapper;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Listener
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mcfdev001.mcfcloud.com/docusign/Listener.asmx")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Listener : System.Web.Services.WebService {
public Listener () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string DocuSignConnectUpdate(DocusignApi.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation DocuSignEnvelopeInformation)
{
    // sample writing all the bytes to a file
    string envelopeId = "";
    try
    {
        envelopeId = DocuSignEnvelopeInformation.EnvelopeStatus.EnvelopeID;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // could not serialize
        File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\errorlog.txt", "Exception: " + ex.Message);
        throw new SoapException(ex.Message, SoapException.ClientFaultCode);
    }
    return envelopeId;
}
```

}

How to configure this on Docusign ?? Specific question is:
At -
DocuSign Connect Settings > DocuSign Connect for EnvelopeListenStatus 
what should be the value in "URL to publish to:" and "Use Soap Interface (Soap Method: DocuSignConnectUpdate) 
      Namespace: "?

Answer (score 0):

You namespace should be like "http://mcfdev001.mcfcloud.com/" and declare as "http://mcfdev001.mcfcloud.com" in DocuSign connect interface.